# Parsley JS 2.x - how do you validate hidden fields?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I would like to validate hidden fields, so essentially I want to remove `input[type=hidden]` from parsley's list of excluded form elements. I've tried explicitly setting excluded elements in parsley's options, but hidden fields are still not validated. E.g:

```
$(element).parsley({
    excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit]'
});
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your form with the hidden field? Also, what is your `element` in that JS?

Comment: `$(element)` is the form parsley is bound to. Yep, the form posts fine and dandy and otherwise works as expected. It just will not validate the hidden field.

Comment: I should note, a workaround is to use a regular text input hidden with CSS (e.g. `display: none;`). However it should be possible to have parsley validate hidden fields from what I've read, hence the query. Perhaps a bug in parsley? Or user error...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a bug.

Take this form:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddeninput" value="" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

With the following javascript, even though we tell Parsley to validate hidden fields, it does not work:

```
$("#myForm").parsley({
    excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]',
    inputs: 'input, textarea, select, input[type=hidden], :hidden',
});
```

However, if you define this as a [global configuration](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-global-configuration), it does work

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
    excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]',
    inputs: 'input, textarea, select, input[type=hidden], :hidden',
};

$("#myForm").parsley();
```

Comment: Maybe @guillaumepotier can provide adicional details.

Comment: Thanks for investigating milz, much appreciated. At least it can be defined as a global config.

Comment: This has been fixed. Moreover it's a horrible idea to put `:hidden` in the inputs list (slow & redundant). See https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/664

Comment: problem if the hidded elements became visible, not validate

Answer (score 1):

what i did was: make input field readonly and hide via css.

Comment: This should not be an answer but a comment instead.

Comment: I have flagged it, but moderator declined

Comment: this was what I ended up having to do. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, yet even when I set up the global configuration it was not working.
The problem essentially, was that I was redefining the options.

Global config:

```
window.ParsleyConfig = {
  excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]',
  inputs: 'input, textarea, select, input[type=hidden], :hidden',
};
```

In my code I had to dynamically change the inputs. Then, I set them to the default:

```
instance = $('form.parsley-validate').parsley(inputs: "input, textarea, select, input[type=hidden], :hidden")
```

Which I had to change to

```
instance = $('form.parsley-validate').parsley(inputs: "input, textarea, select, input[type=hidden], :hidden", excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]')
```

To takeaway: If you change the config, you have to override all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in parsley, in fact someone has already opened an issue regarding it, see: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/664, but unfortunately nothing has been done yet. Basically, after analyzing the source code of parsley the issue is that the options of the parsleyFormInstance are being ignored if the field is already being excluded globally. There is the following if statement deciding this:

```
else if (this.$element.is(this.options.inputs) && !this.$element.is(this.options.excluded))
```

In order to solve this, I have added the following line of code:

```
options = parsleyFormInstance == null ? options : parsleyFormInstance.options;
```

exactly before the OptionsFactory is initialized on line 2160

```
this.OptionsFactory = new ParsleyOptionsFactory(ParsleyDefaults, ParsleyUtils.get(window, 'ParsleyConfig') || {}, options, this.getNamespace(options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method of excluding hidden field when initializing parsley. But it comes with a downside for some scenarios where you have to dynamically hide/un-hide sections of form. Another alternative method is to override the "validated" event, and check inside if the field is hidden or not.

See the below code snippet:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:validated', function(fieldInstance){
if (fieldInstance.$element.is(":hidden")) {
    fieldInstance._ui.$errorsWrapper.css('display', 'none');
    fieldInstance.validationResult = true;
    return true;
}});
```