# How to validate fields with display: none using Parsley JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsley.js

I have a div element which has css display: none and later made visible dynamically. How do I validate fields inside the div using Parsley JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsley JS 2.x - how do you validate hidden fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162059/parsley-js-2-x-how-do-you-validate-hidden-fields)

Comment: That question has answer for hidden fields. In my case, it is display: none property.

Comment: [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do exactly, but you can play around with `excluded` and `inputs` setting to include / exclude anything you want.

By default, `Parsley` excludes hidden inputs.

A helpful setting is to use `disabled` state instead of visibility to decide if a field should be validated, although you can't set that with CSS rules...