# Parsley not validating a form after it is displayed by jQuery show()

Tags: javascript, validation, show-hide, hidden, parsley.js

I have a form

```
  <div id="winForm">
    <div class="container pt-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-none d-md-block iGoToDashboard" style=""><i class="fas fa-arrow-left">&nbsp;</i>Dashboard</a>
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="d-block d-md-none iGoToDashboard" style="font-size: 20px;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 text-center">
          <h3 class="" id="htmlNomeCommessa">COMMESSA </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
        </div>
      </div>
      <form id="iCommessaForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

that is normally hidden by JQuery

```
$("#winForm").hide();
```

and should be validated using Parsley when shown

```
$("#winForm").show();
```

```
$("#iCommessaForm").parsley({
    errorClass: 'has-danger',
    successClass: 'has-success',
    classHandler: function(ParsleyField) {
      return ParsleyField.$element.closest('.form-group');
    },
    errorsContainer: function(ParsleyField) {
      return ParsleyField.$element.closest('.form-group');
    },
    errorsWrapper: '<span class="form-text text-danger"></span>',
    errorTemplate: '<span></span>'
  }).on('form:validate', function() {
    $("#iCommessaForm").addClass('was-validated');
  });

....

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block salva" id="iCommessa__button"><i class="fas fa-save mr-2"></i>Salva</button>
```

I know that Parsley does not validate hidden field and I tried this solution
[Parsley JS 2.x - how do you validate hidden fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162059/parsley-js-2-x-how-do-you-validate-hidden-fields)
without success.
Any suggestion to validate this form?
Thanks.

Comment: Difficult to answer without a working minimal example

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot share the example as we use Parsley with Electron to get a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was caused by a button

```
type="button"
```

instead of

```
type="submit"
```

Thanks.